# How to save params when your saving for a different user in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am building this page where teachers (a kind of user) can edit settings of their students. Every student can tell their teacher what instrument they play and teachers can let their students know what chords they have mastered.

**Student page**
P.S. friend = student

```
= form_for :friend_instrument do |f|
  %br
  %h4.media-heading.text-post.search-result.center Basic chords
  %hr
  .half
    = f.label :c, "C chord"
    = f.select :c, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :d, "D chord"
    = f.select :d, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :e, "E chord"
    = f.select :e, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :f, "F chord"
    = f.select :f, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :g, "G chord"
    = f.select :g, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :a, "A chord"
    = f.select :a, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'
  .half
    = f.label :b, "B chord"
    = f.select :b, [['No', false], ['Yes', true]], {}, class: 'form-control'                               
  = f.submit "Update #{instrument.name} chords #{friend.full_name} mastered", class: 'btn btn-primary form-control'
```

**user_controller**

```
  def students
    @instrument = Instrument.all
  end
  private
  def user_attributes
    params.require(:user).permit(:profile_picture, :cover_photo, :username, :full_name, :facebook_url, :featured_song, :soundcloud_url, :twitter_url, :location, :date_of_birth, :about, :website, :phone, :terms, :playlist_id, :subscribed, :password, :sort_user, :school_is, instrument_ids: [])
  end
```

**user model**

```
  has_many :user_instruments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instruments, through: :user_instruments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :instruments
```

**instrument model**

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_instruments
  has_many :users, through: :user_instruments

  has_many :meeting_instruments
  has_many :meetings, through: :meeting_instruments
end
```

**user instrument model**

```
class UserInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :instrument
end
```

I tried to add user_instruments_attributes but no luck!
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_instruments` on user?  And, to make sure, you have `b`, `c`, `d`, ect. boolean columns on `user_instrument`?

Comment: Thx for the reply, I will add that I had  "accepts_nested_attributes_for :instruments allready"

Comment: And yes, this is my migration files for the chords:

class AddChordsToIntruments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :instruments, :c, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :d, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :e, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :f, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :g, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :a, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :instruments, :b, :boolean, default: false
  end
end

Comment: not `instruments` in the user class, `user_instruments`.  You need accepts nested attributes_for :instrument in the user_instrument class.  It only goes one level, it doesn't go through.

Comment: Thx again, then I get this error: 'No association found for name `instruments'. Has it been defined yet?'

Comment: You named the association "instrument" (`belongs_to :instrument`)

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep that on the students side of things. The change you want to make is to allow teachers to update the attributes of students. You want to use cancan or [access granted](https://github.com/chaps-io/access-granted) (I like access granted) to set who can update what.